# Laravel Routes not Found

Tags: laravel, routes

I am working with Xampp as the server.  For some reason I can't get my routes to function correctly.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return "hello";
});

Route::get('about', function () {
    return "Hello World";
});
```

When I navigate to localhost/laravel/laravel/public/ I get the page that says "Hello".

When I navigate to localhost/laravel/laravel/public/about I get an error saying:

"Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:"

[Image of Routes on Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aVOg.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
Route::get('about', function () {
    return "Hello World";
});
```

to

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return "Hello World";
});
```

you just missed the `/` in front of about.

To see which routes are set up run the following form command line (post the result in your question by editing your question)

```
php artisan route:list
```

start a development server by running the following in your command line

```
php artisan serve
```

after that try browsing to

```
localhost:8000
```

and then

```
localhost:8000/about
```

Comment: Works perfect on that server.  XAMPP issue?

Comment: Just through the normal route.  Main website default install.  Laravel 4 worked fine.

Comment: I think you have to look at your .htaccess file from this point